# How to check pdf->security->print option using php or jquery code for the uploaded pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

In my application user uploads  pdf files ,and i need to check(dynamically) that the uploaded pdf file->security options like printing option is set to allowed or not allowed to move further in my application using php or javascript coding.if the pdf file allows the printing i need to extact pages from it if not i need to throw a error to the user that pdf wont support printing??

```
Searched alot in google but ended up with no solution?

Any suggestions?
```